# Where can I find good a tutorial for creating a simple Flash movie using Adobe Flash CS4?

Tags: tutorial, adobe-flash

Where can I find good a tutorial for creating a simple Flash movie using Adobe Flash CS4?

I want to create an App of a children's picture book. Each page is a single image, so I want a tutorial that walks me through adding images into a movie, with the ability to 'turn the page' to the next page/image.

Answer (score 1):

One of Adobe's less-publicized efforts in the last few years has been the huge number of online video tutorials they're made (or have had other folks, like lynda.com, totaltraining.com and video2brain.com make for them). They're all free and there's a ton of them for every app.

This is the link to the Flash CS4 course in the Learning section of tv.adobe.com:
http://tv.adobe.com/show/learn-flash-professional-cs4/